# Adding an SSH public key to a new account without enabling password authentication

Tags: ssh, authentication, ssh-keys

On a SSH server, I have the following (truncated) configuration:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

On my client, I have a key pair, and have added my public key on the server with:

```
ssh-copy-id <my-server>
```

Now, if I change the `PasswordAuthentication` option to `no`, the only way to connect to my SSH server will be by validating the keys, right?

Then, if I want to add a **new** client, I need to:

- temporarily enable the `PasswordAuthentication` option from an already authorized client and use `ssh-copy-id` from the new client
- or copy/paste the new client's public key in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of the server from the already authorized client.

But I find these methods quite boring.

**Question:** Is there an easier way to add a **new** key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server?

Answer (score 2):

You can alter new user's `authorized_keys` file just as any other file on the system. You do not need to do it using the user's account. Any account with a write access to the file will do. I.e. typically the `root` account (or `sudo`).

The `ssh-copy-id` just simplifies the process by creating all the folders and files for you, with correct permissions. When doing this manually you need to ensure all this on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, the answers to each of your questions is yes. Whether or not you find this method 'boring', it is an accepted way to allow access to a new client.

One other possible way to add the new key is to use an existing client to copy and paste the contents of the public key from the new client to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file for the user in question on the target machine - making sure that the permissions and ownership is set correctly. This obviates the need to temporarily allow use of passwords for authentication (which would need to be relayed to the user attempting the `ssh-copy-id` operation anyway).